# Does an ext4 writer for Windows exist?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning, ext4

Are there any applications that can write to ext4 file systems from Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this, but [this project's driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) claims to be able to let Windows access it. Whether there are specific applications that can, or cannot, use it, you would probably just have to test.

> Support writing to ext4 volumes w/ flex_bg

and [the FAQ](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=7) says that these systems are supported:

> Windows 2000, xp, 2003, Vista, Win7 (X86, AMD64)

I would be wary of these drivers, in general, not this one specifically. As I was searching, I found numerous warnings regarding the possibility of lost data, so make sure you are backed up. I did not find any actual cases of lost data though.

Comment: @soandos Yikes, but in my defense, it is almost 3am here. :)

Comment: Almost like you are describing yourself and not the drivers ;) (and same here)

Comment: @soandos Both really. :)

Comment: well, its partially cause the drivers are still quite WIP, and in general, almost all non native/userspace drivers warn of possible dataloss, just in case.

Comment: This tool doesn't seem to work anymore. Running Windows 10 Home 1607 64-bit.

Comment: I also had no luck with this tool on Windows 10 pro